# How can i get the selected text in a richTextBox using the mouse and display the text in real time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

Today when I click with them mouse on the rich-textbox text window and drag the mouse to the right it's highlighting the text in blue.

What I want to do is to simulate this situation but this time:

1. To make when moving the mouse and highlighting text so it will be color in yellow not as by default blue.
2. To make that while the mouse left button is clicked and pressed down nonstop and i move the mouse over a text show me this text in a label in real time.

What I did so far:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Clicks == 1 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                int positionStart = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition
                                       (new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionStart;

            }
        }
```

Not sure if mouse-down is the correct event and maybe i need to use also mouse-up event.
Or maybe mouse move too.

Now I have the SelectionStart index.

But what should I do next ?

Edit:

For displaying in real time the selectedtext it's working but for coloring it in real time not working. I tried:

```
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        PointF drawPoint = new PointF(0, 0);

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.SelectedText, drawFont, drawBrush,drawPoint);
        }
```

But it's not coloring anything at all.
I checked with breakpoint it's getting there but not coloring any text.
What i want is in in realtime when in the mousemove event it will color the selectedtext.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        label1.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
    }
}

private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
}
```

Do the main function on the mouse move and make sure that the left mouse button is down. Then to catch if the person pressed ctrl A use the selection changed function. I have tried and tested this and it has worked.

As for making the selection colour yellow you will have to go into the onpaint function of the richtextbox.

Comment: Why not simply set the Selectioncolor from the start? And why the MouseMove?

Comment: What do you mean??? Simply take the `richTextBox1_SelectionChanged` event form Brendon's answer, set `richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;` in the form constructor and your're good..!  The `Mousemove` is __not__ neccessary. Nor __anything__ in the `Paint` event!

Comment: TaW i tried your code not using the move event only the SelectionChanged event but it's coloring the whole text in yellow already. I want that only when i click the mouse left button and drag/move the mouse it will highlight it in yellow in real time. The same as you are doing today like in notepad but the default in all programs is blue. I want to be able to highlight in yellow then stop mouse up then highlight other parts.

Comment: You are right, don't know how it seemed to work here. I'm afraid changing the selection highlighting is not possible. The part that copies the selection to the label is as simple as the one line, but changing the highlight color in only the RTB won't work I believe..

Answer (score 0):

In order to highlight the text when mouse over try to define an attached property:

```
public class TextBoxProperties : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightTextOnFocusProperty =
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightTextOnFocus",
typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxProperties),
new PropertyMetadata(false, HighlightTextOnFocusPropertyChanged));


    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildrenAttribute(IncludeDescendants = false)]
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public static bool GetHighlightTextOnFocus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HighlightTextOnFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHighlightTextOnFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HighlightTextOnFocusProperty, value);
    }

    private static void HighlightTextOnFocusPropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sender = obj as UIElement;
        if (sender != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                sender.GotKeyboardFocus += OnKeyboardFocusSelectText;
                sender.PreviewMouseMove += OnMouseMoveSetFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                sender.GotKeyboardFocus -= OnKeyboardFocusSelectText;
                sender.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseMoveSetFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnKeyboardFocusSelectText(
        object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.SelectAll();
        }
    }

    private static void OnMouseMoveSetFocus(
        object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = FindAncestor<TextBox>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

        if (tb == null)
            return;

        if (!tb.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            tb.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        };
        return null;
    }
}
```

Add it in xaml like this :

```
                 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
                          Text="{Binding TestProperty}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          converters:TextBoxProperties.HighlightTextOnFocus="True"
                         />
```

And of course, don't forget your namespace :

```
          xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourProject.Converters"
```

Further more, in order to change the highlight color on your TextBox try to use SelectionBrush :

```
 <TextBox SelectionBrush="Red" SelectionOpacity="0.5"/>
```

Comment: This is a Winforms question. BTW: Does it really take such a complicated code to do in WPF what Winforms can do in two lines??

Comment: @TaW you can choose to write code in code behind files but in order to implement MVVM some mechanisms have to be used. One example would be that attached property and the possibility to declare it in a separate class and reference it from there instead of code behind.